# Install Perl module WWW::Mechanize on Mac

Tags: macos, perl, www-mechanize

I fail to install perl module with CPAN on Mac OS X. Do you have any idea or link for my reference? Thank you.

Comment: How did you try to install it (what exact command did you use)? Have you retried installing the module even if it failed the first time? When did the installation fail (error messages before `cpan` terminated)? Have you tried installing the dependencies manually? What perl are you using?

Comment: my command is sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install www::mechanize'. Thank you.

Comment: I assume you typed `sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install WWW::Mechanize`, as Perl and CPAN are case dependant. Btw, `sudo cpan install WWW::Mechanize` is shorter.

Answer (score 7):

I urge you to install [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) to create a local environment into which you can safely install Perl modules from CPAN without clobbering or worrying about the standard OS Perl.  You will also gain the benefit of a current Perl version, far above what comes standard with your MAC.

You will need a C compilation environment 'XCode 4' in order to install `perlbrew`. Your install disks or the online Apple APP store offers those.  Sign-up as an Apple Developer and you can download the toolset.

Comment: JRFerguson - Thank you for your answer. I cannot install perlbrew by using command "sudo cpan App::perlbrew". I am using MAC OS 10.8. Also, I have installed xocde 4.3 into my MAC already. Thank you.

Comment: The `perlbrew` documentation cited notes, "If it is installed with cpan, the perlbrew executable should be installed as /usr/bin/perlbrew or /usr/local/bin/perlbrew. For all users who want to use perlbrew, a prior perlbrew init needs to be executed."  It is simplest to install into your HOME directory with `curl -kL http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash`.